# how to begin my analysis? panel data, lots of missingness, and around 100 variables

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, panel-data, missing-data

I have an extremely unbalanced panel dataset over ten time periods， with a large percentage of missingness, and a high number of mixed types variables and the dependent variable is binary. I want to ask:
1. how to select independent variables across the time period? 
2. how to deal with missingness? some of the variables with over 90% missingness
3. which goes first? Variables selection or imputation?
finally, the software I can use is STATA SAS and R, but R is just beginner level.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interesting first question but why couldn't you have been given a less complicated problem? Your query has no easy answers, much less hard and fast cookbook rules, and such answers as do exist are not for the unsophisticated. That said, CV is not intended to be a resource for software-specific questions so don't expect responses to include recommendations wrt your concerns about R or Stata.

Issues wrt missing data have seen decades of literature and research probably beginning with Little and Rubin's book *Statistical Analysis with Missing Data*. The key thing is to identify the mechanism(s) underlying the missingness, e.g., is it *missing at random* (MAR), *missing completely at random* (MCAR), ignorable, nonignorable, and so on. These topics have been well developed (e.g., this Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data offers a good stake-in-the-ground but my go-to reference is Paul Allison's thoughtful, highly readable, more than 15 year old Sage book *Missing Data*). Depending on the mechanism, imputation may provide more or less representative (unbiased) results. If the missingness is *nonignorable* and/or systematic then there are no good options or solutions.

You don't indicate whether or not the missing values are in the dependent variable (left hand side of the equation) or the independent predictors (right hand side). One useful rule of thumb is that imputation wrt the DV is not recommended. Unfortunately there are no conventions, norms or rules of thumb wrt how much missingness in the predictors is too much. Such decisions are always left to the analyst. My experience is that anything north of 50% missing begins to make me squeamish.

To answer your question, imputation should precede selection. The next decision concerns *which* imputation method should be used. As outlined in the Wiki piece there are many approaches to plugging missing values. In an *ASA* short course, Rubin gave a few helpful hints about this process. Among the most easily implemented solutions for continuously distributed information is to plug missing values with the mean or the median -- an approach that in Rubin's view was definitely a bad idea as it will result in a spike in the *pdf* of the variable's distribution at that value. Out of all the options, his view was that the least biasing was model-based multiple imputation and suggests the standard approach of evaluating the extent to which the results of the process of imputation are *good* by comparing summary statistics of the *before* and *after* imputed variables. Large differences or deviations between the unplugged and plugged statistics are not desirable.

Other suggestions made by Rubin included:

- Using the DV as a predictor in model-based imputation
- When there are multiple variables with missing data (as in your case) rank them from least to most wrt the proportion of missing information and begin the process of imputation with variables containing the least missing data
- Once plugged use these variables as predictors for imputation wrt variables lower down the list

Finally, variable selection is one of those topics about which every statistician and their brother has an opinion and published paper. One method is the *lasso* which the author of the (now shuttered) *Normal Deviate* blog ranked as one of the top 10 statistical innovations of the recent era.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
My idea was to use  MICE (multiple imputations by chained equations)  to impute whole variables in SAS 10 times by year,  then generate like ten imputed datasets, and run a pooled logit regression with the stepwise method to find out those significant variables for each year. Finally, selecting those common variables as predictors. I am not sure if it is ok, but the first step failed as SAS system printed like "all value is same for that variables". and now I don't know what to do next!

Comment: BTW, is that possible to analyse panel data with different sets of variables? Can I select variables first and then dealing the missing data?
DV  is all observed. The missing pattern is arbitrary. WRT missing mechanism, by default, I consider all missing variables as MAR.

Comment: If you aren't able to leverage SAS' Technical Support you should pose your software questions on either SEs Stack Overflow or the SAS Support Community Q&A website.

Comment: @lance if you're amenable we can move this discussion to chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=stats.stackexchange.com   One goal would be to edit your question with the goal of getting it reopened. No guarantees anything will work though.

Comment: @ DJohnson I'd like to do that, but it seems that I don't have enough rep (20 rep?) to chat in the room. I am new here and this is my first question.

Comment: Sorry about that. A few pointers then...e.g., how was your data gathered? A survey? Pulled from secondary sources?  How big is your sample? What is your unit of analysis? In other words, since it's panel data what do the cross sections consist of? People? Companies? Some digital entity? You mention 'unbalanced data' over 'ten time periods,' would you be more specific about what 'unbalanced' means? E.g., does it mean that the units of analysis are not consistently observed for all 10 periods? That they do not start or end at the same time? ctd>>

Comment: >>ctd...If you were to describe the variables a bit -- just at a high level like what are you trying to understand or predict (the DV), what are the predictors, etc. Although this guideline is widely ignored it's always wise not to mention specific software. This makes your query more generalizable. In addition, it never hurts to include a small table of sample data or alternatively some kind of data schematic. Finally CV being dominated by theoretically trained statisticians. Given that it never hurts to include some kind of Latex-like representation of the theoretical model to be fitted.